# Derivation of impact free Boltzmann equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

When deriving the impact-free boltzmann equation ( $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \vec{v} \cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{x}} + \vec{a} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{v}} = 0$) I have a question about the notion. Basically we are looking at the change in particles in a given volume $V$ which is given by:

$\frac{d}{dt} \int_V f(\vec{x}, \vec{v}, t) dV = - \int_{\partial V} (\vec{v}, \vec{a}) \cdot f(\vec{x}, \vec{v}, t)d\vec{A}$

Can somebody intuitively explain why the right side is the flux of particles through the surface of $V$? I don't exactly know how to interpret $f(\vec{x}, \vec{v}, t)d\vec{A}$ since in my script only $f(\vec{x}, \vec{v}, t) d^3v d^3x$ is explicitly defined as the amount of particles with position and velocity $(\vec{x}, \vec{v}) \in d^3 x d^3x$ at time $t$. How does this translate to a surface integral? And how do I interpret it when I multiply the scalar function $f$ with the vector $(\vec{v}, \vec{a})$?

Comment: Hi user17574 - we prefer each separate question to be asked on its own. Could you edit this to contain only one of your questions, and post the other one as a separate post?

Comment: Oh, didn't know about this rule. I'll edit asap.